# Have anyone have idea about react minified error # 130 that occured in my production build while rendering a specific component

Tags: reactjs, build, vite

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

no idea how to solve this error. I tried making minified false but it didn't work. It works perfectly locally. but when I take the build and then host the build that time the error occurs. help me to solve this issue